# SQL Masking A Mapping Field In The Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a view to extract data from a table and load that data into a fixed file which will be loaded into a system. The view will map the table column to a particular format.

There is one column, Account_Number, which needs to be masked as the column has sensitive information.

My logic to mask the value is to shift the number to the next place in numberline.

so, if the number is 0 then 1, 4 then 5, etc. I am not able to come with the logic in the view itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "Schema1"."VW_ActiveTraders" ("FUND", "NAME", "CITY", "ACN") AS 

Select  
TD_Fund as FUND,
Name as NAME,
City as CITY,
Account_Number as ACN

FROM Trader1 -- Table Name

Account Number 
023457456
123456789
012345678

Masked Account Number
134568567
012345678
123456789
```

Please note that Account Number column has more than 1000 entries.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [TRANSLATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html#GUID-80F85ACB-092C-4CC7-91F6-B3A585E3A690) to shift the numbers

```
with dt as (
select '023457456' ACN from dual union all
select '123456789' ACN from dual union all
select '012345678' ACN from dual)
select ACN,
TRANSLATE(ACN,'0123456789','1234567890') as ACN_WEAK_MASK
from dt;

ACN       ACN_WEAK_
--------- ---------
023457456 134568567
123456789 234567890
012345678 123456789
```

But note, that this is not a real *masking* of sensitive information. It is very easy to **unmask** the information and get the original acount ID.

An often used masking is e.g. `012345678` gets `******678`.

Comment: Thanks @Marmite Bomber, appreciate your reply. The column Account number has more than 1000 entries so is there any other way where we can mask the numbers in the original view itself and without having to input all numbers of column? Weak masking should be ok as the recipient system will only see the changed numbers. The problem with ******678 is that every account number is unique and each mask number needs to be traced back to the original number.

Comment: @ClaudeTi   `TRANSLATE` is called with 3 parameters. The first one is the account number, the two other are fixed and define the conversion. There is no need to *input all account numbers*.

Comment: With the TRANSLATE method you don't have to input any numbers of the column.  That WITH statement (CTE) is just a way to pull in some test data for a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

@MarmiteBomber @Stilgar - Thanks so much for clarification and help on the answer.

I just tweaked the query and it ran successfully.

Changed Query

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "Schema1"."VW_ActiveTraders" ("FUND", "NAME", "CITY", "ACN") AS

Select
TD_Fund as FUND,
Name as NAME,
City as CITY,
--Account_Number as ACN
TRANSLATE(Account_Number,'0123456789','1234567890') as ACN,

FROM Trader1 -- Table Name

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------